# Meaning of “penetrate at a bound”

Tags: etymology, phrase-meaning

I was reading Isaac Asimov’s [*Foundation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_(Asimov_novel)) recently when a phrase stuck out to me: “penetrate at a bound [to].” In context, with boldface added:

> “The best men on the planets of the kingdoms are sent here to the Foundation each year and educated into the priesthood. And the best of these remain here as research students. If you think that those who are left, with practically no knowledge of the elements of science, or worse still, with the distorted knowledge the priests receive, can **penetrate at a bound** to nuclear power, to electronics, to the theory of the hyperwarp—you have a very romantic and foolish idea of science. It takes lifetimes of training and an excellent brain to get that far.”

From the context, it seems clear that “to penetrate at a bound” is to understand both how something works and why. (I know that “penetrate” can be used to mean “understand,” as in “a penetrating intellect,” but “at a bound” has me at a loss.) Is my reading correct? What is the etymology of the phrase, and was it ever particularly common?

Asimov was American. I believe this passage was written in 1942–44, although it may have been edited somewhat in 1951 when the short stories of *Foundation* were combined into a book. The text above was taken from the Kindle version.

Comment: I would read _bound_ quite literally here, to mean ‘leap’. _Penetrate_ is perhaps a bit odd combined with the notion of a leap; _advance_ would have been easier to understand. I read it as meaning, “if you think [they] can advance in one giant leap to understanding nuclear power, etc.”, which seems a logical enough thing to say.

Comment: It's the same sense of "bound" as was used in the Superman intro: "able to leap tall buildings in a single bound"

Comment: These days, the idiom might be something like "make the quantum leap to nuclear power".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**at a bound**: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22037#eid15974064)

> by an instantaneous movement.

Etymology: same link

> to take at the (first) bound   (a1556)

Google [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20a%20bound&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20bound%3B%2Cc0) show a peak use around 1900 then tapering to infrequently used.  I did not search the books to sense a reason for this.  In AmE I hear and see **in a bound** and **at a bound** infrequently, the former more frequently than the latter.